Assembly 8086 TASM - TEA Algorithm - How to split 8-byte variable into two different variables of 4 bytes?
I want to write the TEA algorithm in assembly 8086 (TASM), and I am stuck in the first steps of splitting the plaintext (block) variable into 2 variables and the key into 4 variables (k1, k2, k3, k4).
I know the limit of the plaintext (block) is 64 bits (8 bytes)
and the limit of the key is 128 bits (16 bytes).
The plaintext variable is stored in the data section:
plainText db 8 dup('$')

and these are the two variables of the plaintext:
p1 db 4 dup('$')

p2 db 4 dup('$')

The key variable is stored like this:
key db 16 dup("$")

and the 4 split keys:
k0 db ?

k1 db ?

k2 db ?

k3 db ?

This is my current encryption section for taking the input from the user:
proc encryptionSelection
    print plainTextPrompt
    inputString [plainText] ; Block Limit: 64 bits -> 8 bytes

    call printLine
    print p1
    call printLine
    print p2

    print keyPrompt
    inputString [key] ; Key Limit:  128 bits -> 16 bytes

    ; Encryption Logic Here...
    ret
endp encryptionSelection

macro inputString storage
    pusha
    mov ah, 0ah
    lea dx, storage
    int 21h
    popa
endm inputString

macro print value
    pusha
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset value
    int 21h
    popa

endm print

I tried many ways and googled a lot, but I couldn't find any solutions.

There is really no reason to split anything, you can just index your plainText. But if you insist you can of course copy it over, e.g. mov ax, plainText; mov dx, plainText + 2; mov p1, ax; mov p1 + 2, dx;  (repeat for p2 with plainText + 4 and plainText + 6).

You're using int 21h function 0Ah wrong. It takes a buffer with a special setup; the first byte indicates how long the buffer is (excluding the first two bytes) and the second byte should be initialised to zero and will be set by the DOS to the number of text bytes actually sent by the user. This data starts with the third byte of the buffer. Your buffer size must accommodate enough space for your desired data, as text, plus a terminating Carriage Return placed by the DOS. Refer to the interrupt list, https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/210a.html#2602


and the 4 split keys:


k0 db ?  
k1 db ?  
k2 db ?  
k3 db ?


The key has 16 bytes, so split in 4, I would expect these to be dwords rather than bytes!

plainText db 8 dup('$')
p1 db 4 dup('$')
p2 db 4 dup('$')


Your inputString macro is using the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah, and you are not supplying the correct buffer to DOS! See How buffered input works.
The correct definition for plainText would be:
plainText db 9, 0, 9 dup('$')
p1 db 4 dup('$')
p2 db 4 dup('$')

One way to split the inputted 8 bytes is to copy the following way:
print plainTextPrompt
inputString [plainText] ; Block Limit: 64 bits -> 8 bytes
mov  di, offset p1
mov  si, offset plainText+2
mov  cx, 8
rep movsb

But the most efficient way would be to reorganize the buffers:
plainText db 9, 0
p1        dd 0      ;;
p2        dd 0      ; Together 9 bytes of inputbuffer
          db 0      ;;
          db 0      ; 1 extra byte for word-alignment
key       db 17, 0
k0        dd 0      ;;
k1        dd 0      ;;;
k3        dd 0      ; Together 17 bytes of inputbuffer
k4        dd 0      ;;;
          db 0      ;;
          db 0      ; 1 extra byte for word-alignment

Then no copying is required and you can easily access your separate variables.
